# Solr admin console - how to use Request Handler field?

Tags: solr

I am on Solr 3.6.1. And trying to figure out how to use the admin console to query a non-default handler. I tried the following variations:

```
/CustomHandler
/select&qt=CustomHandler
/select/CustomHandler
```

None of those work and I have this nagging feeling that I am missing something very obvious but just can't think of it.

[image]

Comment: How have you defined /CustomHandler in your solrconfig.xml file?

Comment: Yes, I have and it work fine when I query Solr from my code with http://server.com/solr/select?qt=CustomHandler&wt=json...

Comment: Here is the actual CustomHandler definition from solrconfig.xml:<requestHandler name="CustomHandler" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
      <str name="defType">edismax</str>
      <str name="qf">.....

Comment: Just use the qt parameter as is CustomHandler in the request handler field without and leading slash.

Comment: Tried qt=CustomHandler, no go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the definition of the requestHandler, I believe you need to add the forward slash in front of the name.

```
<requestHandler name="/CustomHandler" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 ....
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: I just tried creating my own CustomHandler in the solrconfig.xml file that comes in the /example/solr folder with the 3.6.1 Solr download and I was able to successfully query Solr specifying /CustomHandler in the Request Handler section of the Admin page. I did get an error when I removed the leading slash. Unfortunately, I cannot see the entirety of your requestHandler settings they were cut off. What if you copy the default /select handler settings as a start to see if maybe it is something in your handlers settings. Also, are you receiving an error message in the browser or in your log?

Comment: Sorry, I had to go take care of other priorities. Just figured out the problem. This fixed now. I knew it was something simple (and stupid on my part). I didn't have / as part of the handler name. Go figure!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try changing `/select&qt=CustomHandler` to `/select?qt=CustomHandler`. (change the ampersand to a dollar-sign)

Comment: Tried that too, that's not it either.

Comment: If you define it using name="/CustomHandler" then you have to call /select?qt=/CustomHandler